# Finger Print recognition system

Tags: c#, fingerprint

i m using vs2008 and SourceAFIS 1.1
i m unable to access any of the methods may someone help me getting started
they(SourceAFIS) gave us the following sample as Program.cs
i want to develope an application which firstly Enrolls users and then identify them if they are enrolled user or not.

```
namespace Sample
{
     public class Program
    {
        // Inherit from Fingerprint in order to add Filename field
        [Serializable]
        class MyFingerprint : Fingerprint
        {
            public string Filename;
        }

        // Inherit from Person in order to add Name field
        [Serializable]
        class MyPerson : Person
        {
            public string Name;
        }

        // Initialize path to images
        static readonly string ImagePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine("..", ".."), "images");

        // Shared AfisEngine instance (cannot be shared between different threads though)
        static AfisEngine Afis;

        // Take fingerprint image file and create Person object from the image
        static MyPerson Enroll(string filename, string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enrolling {0}...", name);

            // Initialize empty fingerprint object and set properties
            MyFingerprint fp = new MyFingerprint();
            fp.Filename = filename;
            // Load image from the file, fp.BitmapImage makes a copy of the image, so that we can dispose it afterwards
            Console.WriteLine(" Loading image from {0}...", filename);
            using (Image fromFile = Bitmap.FromFile(filename))
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fromFile))
                    fp.BitmapImage = bitmap;
            // Above update of fp.BitmapImage initialized also raw image in fp.Image
            // Check raw image dimensions, Y axis is first, X axis is second
            Console.WriteLine(" Image size = {0} x {1} (width x height)", fp.Image.GetLength(1), fp.Image.GetLength(0));

            // Execute extraction in order to initialize fp.Template
            Console.WriteLine(" Extracting template...");
            Afis.Extract(fp);
            // Check template size
            Console.WriteLine(" Template size = {0} bytes", fp.Template.Length);

            // Initialize empty person object and set its properties
            MyPerson person = new MyPerson();
            person.Name = name;
            // Add fingerprint to the person
            person.Add(fp);

            return person;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Initialize SourceAFIS
            Afis = new AfisEngine();

            // Enroll some people
            List<MyPerson> database = new List<MyPerson>();
            database.Add(Enroll(Path.Combine(ImagePath, "candidate1.tif"), "Fred Flintstone"));
            database.Add(Enroll(Path.Combine(ImagePath, "candidate2.tif"), "Wilma Flintstone"));
            database.Add(Enroll(Path.Combine(ImagePath, "candidate3.tif"), "Barney Rubble"));

            // Save the database to disk and load it back, just to try out the serialization
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Console.WriteLine("Saving database...");
            using (Stream stream = File.Open("database.dat", FileMode.Create))
                formatter.Serialize(stream, database);
            Console.WriteLine("Reloading database...");
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("database.dat"))
                database = (List<MyPerson>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

            // Enroll visitor with unknown identity
            MyPerson probe = Enroll(Path.Combine(ImagePath, "probe.tif"), "Visitor #12345");

            // Look up the probe using Threshold = 10
            Afis.Threshold = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("Identifying {0} in database of {1} persons...", probe.Name, database.Count);
            MyPerson match = Afis.Identify(probe, database);





            // Null result means that there is no candidate with similarity score above threshold
            if (match == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No matching person found.");
                return;
            }
            // Print out any non-null result
            Console.WriteLine("Probe {0} matches registered person {1}", probe.Name, match.Name);

            // Compute similarity score
            float score = Afis.Verify(probe, match);
            Console.WriteLine("Similarity score between {0} and {1} = {2:F3}", probe.Name, match.Name, score);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any error? or are you asking for sample code?

Comment: actulally i am unable to use functionalities provided by SourceAFIS(SDK)
and yes i am asking for some example code so that i can develope application,
and thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 1):

```
        // Initialize SourceAFIS
        if (Afis == null) Afis = new AfisEngine();

        // Enroll fitst identity
        Fingerprint f = new Fingerprint();
        f.AsBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBoxFinger.Image;

        Person probe = new Person();
        probe.Fingerprints.Add(f);
        Afis.Extract(probe);

        // Enroll second identity            
        Fingerprint f2 = new Fingerprint();
        f2.AsBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBoxVerify.Image;
        Person match = new Person();
        match.Fingerprints.Add(f2);
        Afis.Extract(match);

        // Compute similarity score
        float score = Afis.Verify(probe, match);
```